# I have problems to render my data en each loop with express handlebar

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

I am rendering in a view a table with express handlebars, I set up my Each loop and it brings me the data correctly from my SQL database. The point is that when rendering the data from the  tag with id="importe" passing it inside a script and returning the amount multiplied by a value of variable "dolarblue", it only does it correctly for the first item. Then the rest are blank:

```
{{#each servicios}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{servicioID}}</td>
                            <td>{{descripcion}}</td>
                            <td><div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-{{servicioID}}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="check-{{servicioID}}">
                                </label>
                                </div></td>
                            <td id="importe{{servicioID}}"></td>
                            <td id="total"></td>
                        </tr>
                        {{!-- Cotización dolar --}}
                        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
                        var importe = {{preciousd}}
                        var url = 'https://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest';
                        var data_json = get_data(url);
                        let dolarblue = data_json.blue.value_buy
                        document.getElementById("importe{{servicioID}}").innerHTML = {{preciousd}} * dolarblue;
                        </script>  
                        {{/each}}
```

This is how my table render:

| # | Servicio | Font awesome | Importe | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Web responsive (Inicio + 3 secciones) | checkbox | 89750 |  |
| 2 | Tienda autogestionable | checkbox |  |  |

Can anyone know what is the reason?
Thanks!

I want to fix my code to render all complete data set.

Comment: ```document.getElementById("importe{{servicioID}}").innerHTML = {{preciousd}} * dolarblue;``` The getElementById, only selects one element at a time, so you'd be better off giving it a className

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it after asking the question. When going through the second each it took the same variable names for the script and generated an error. With which I put to the variables of the script the property {{serviceID}} to conform the name and now it runs it correctly. I don't think this is the most efficient solution. But it worked for me.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
                        var url{{servicioID}} = 'https://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest';
                        var data_json{{servicioID}} = get_data(url{{servicioID}});
                        let dolarblue{{servicioID}} = data_json{{servicioID}}.blue.value_sell
                        var importe = {{preciousd}}
                        document.getElementById("importe{{servicioID}}").innerHTML = {{preciousd}} * dolarblue{{servicioID}};
                        </script>
```